# C# Cannot convert from string [] to string

Tags: c#

I have this method and get the above error on the line words.Add(rows); can anyone help? Thanks - Ben

```
private static IEnumerable<string> LoadWords(String filePath)
    {

        List<String> words = new List<String>();

        try
        {
            foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
            {
                string[] rows = line.Split(',');

                words.Add(rows);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

            return words;
    }
```

Comment: For your own information, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891157/an-i-prevent-a-specific-type-using-generic-restrictions/3891439#3891439) Eric Lippert explains why it makes sense for `Add` and `AddRange` are separate functions.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891157/an-i-prevent-a-specific-type-using-generic-restrictions/3891584#3891584) LBushkin goes into a bit more detail, looking at the technical limitations that make this choice necessary.  Without those technical limitations, having two separate functions would still be a good idea, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
words.Add(rows);
```

use this :

```
words.AddRange(rows);
```

`rows` is a string array containing multiple strings, so you have to add them with [`AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Change it to this

```
words.AddRange(rows);
```

You issue is that you are adding an array of items, not a single element.

You use AddRange() when adding a collection that implements `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`

See documentation here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a string array to a list that takes a string.

Try `words.AddRange(rows);`

Answer (score 1):

u r trying to add string of array in a list of array

```
private static IEnumerable<string> LoadWords(String filePath)
    {

        List<String> words = new List<String>();

        try
        {
            foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
            {
                string[] rows = line.Split(',');

                foreach(string str in rows)
                       words.Add(str);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

            return words;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong method. You want the AddRange method.

```
words.AddRange(rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try of this:

```
words.AddRange(rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Add` will take another string, not an array of strings.

Try `.AddRange` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> LoadWords(String filePath)
{

    List<String> words = new List<String>();

    try
    {
        foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
        {
            string[] rows = line.Split(',');

            foreach (String word in rows)
            {
                words.Add(word);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }

        return words;
}
```

Comment: +0: This will work, but just calling `AddRange` is cleaner than a `foreach`.

Comment: I agree, but if the OP needs to see a way to exclude certain words, this would let him see where to add a piece of code to test before inserting.